# Where account is my google calendar API using?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, service-accounts, google-calendar-api

I'm unsure where I can view the calendar I'm interacting with?

I created the project using my google work account. In the [cloud console](https://console.developers.google.com), it shows I technically have a `service account` for my codes authentication. Cloud console confirms I'm getting a 200 on my create event request. No event in my calendar for my work Gmail though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that service accounts are not you.  A service account is like a dummy user, It has its own Google drive account, Google calendar account and probably a bunch more.

So when you insert something into a service accounts primary calendar its inserting into its account not yours.   There is no web access to a service accounts data.  You will need to do a event.list for example to see the events you have added.

What you can do is have the service account share its calendar with you and then you will be able to see its calendar in your google calendar web view.   If memory serves you have to add it as an [acl rule](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl).  You could also share your calendar with the service account and then it will be able to update that.

Useful links [Sharing calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing#sharing_calendars) my tutorial on [service accounts](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/)

Now as for Google for work.  You are going to have to add the service account to that somehow grant it access to the Google for work calendar.   I dont have access to that so cant be of much help.